# Selecting users with entries in table and lookup table

Tags: mysql

I have a comment system where multiple users can receive the same comment. I'm trying to find a count of all users in a given group who have given or received a comment in the last 7 days. This involves 3 tables:
**user**
id
reportsTo

**comment**
id
sender
date

**comment_recipient**
user_id
comment_id

Here is what I have, but I don't think it is quite right yet, as I'm getting unexpected numbers. What am I missing? Also, I don't think I'm handling this correctly if no comments exist?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM user AS u
JOIN comment AS c ON c.sender=u.id
JOIN comment_recipient AS cr ON cr.user_id=u.id
JOIN comment AS c1 ON c1.id=cr.comment_id
WHERE u.reportsTo=:teamId
AND u.id<>:teamId
AND (c.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY )
OR c1.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY ))
GROUP BY u.id;
```

.

```
What I am getting:
```

I'm currently getting a count higher than the number of users that should be in that team

```
Desired Output:
```

I'm trying to get a count of users which have a specific reportsTo(user.id) entry

Comment: can you please supply the 3 create table stmts hopefully containing indexes? summarize your output for a given select, and desired results. so 3 things would help.

Comment: I didn't include the whole table for these because there are several fields in user and comment and they aren't relevant to the question. I'm trying to get a count of users which have a specific reportsTo(user.id) entry, but I'm currently getting a count higher than the number of users that should be in that team

Comment: just for clarity, you are using or re-using table user for team group concept. you use term team and group. and this construct happens with reportsTo column self-joining or filtering to user.id with your select stmt that has `AND u.id<>:teamId`  ... i guess that is a question of mine, as you have no team or group table

Comment: Ah I see Drew, :teamId will always be a user.id(It is the id of a user who manages other users), so I'm selecting users who all have the same manager(reportsTo), but I don't want to include the manager themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- drop table user
create table user
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    reportsTo int null
);

insert into user(reportsTo) values(null);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(null);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(2);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(2);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(2);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(1);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(1);
insert into user(reportsTo) values(1);
-- select * from user;


-- drop table comment;
create table comment
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    sender int not null,
    theDate datetime not null
);
-- delete from comment;
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (1,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (2,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (2,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (3,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (3,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (3,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (4,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (4,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (4,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (4,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (5,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (5,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (5,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (5,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (5,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (7,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (7,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (8,now());
insert into comment (sender,theDate) values (8,now());

-- select * from comment;

-- drop table comment_recipient;
create table comment_recipient
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    comment_id int not null,    -- refers to comment.id which is a autu pk
    user_id int not null
    -- not this table could use some additional index help but it is just a stub
);

insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (2,4);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (2,6);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (3,6);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (3,3);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (4,8);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (4,6);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (16,8);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (17,8);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (18,7);
insert into comment_recipient (comment_id,user_id) values (19,7);
-- select * from comment_recipient
```

.

```
-- comment sender last 7 days that reports to certain 'team/group'
select distinct u.id 
from user u
join comment c on c.sender=u.id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, c.theDate, now())<169
where u.reportsTo=2
union
-- comment recipient last 7 days that reports to certain 'team/group'
select distinct u.id 
from user u
join comment_recipient cr on cr.user_id=u.id 
join comment c on c.id=cr.comment_id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, c.theDate, now())<169
where u.reportsTo=2
```

Comment: Yes! and how would I just select the total of distinct ids vs getting them as rows, or should I just count the rows?

Comment: either based on front end prog lang. php has rowcount built in. java c# anything can tell u that based on result set coming back. u dont need to loop and increment a counter

Answer (score 0):

I may be oversimplifying the answer and you might want something more, but couldn't you just do a simple SQL query on the comment_recipient table? If you want also the number of posts by a user (e.g. the comments) just join it with the comments table as well.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM comment_recipient, user, comment 
WHERE user.id=comment_recipient.user_id
AND user.id= comment.sender
AND date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
AND user.reportsTo IN (SELECT reportsTo FROM users WHERE reportsTo=XXX)
```

As per the comments, here is another way to possibly accomplish this.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM comment_recipient, comment
WHERE comment.sender = comment_recipient.user_id
AND date >= DATE(NOW()) - INERVAL 7 DAY
WHEE user.reportsTo IN (SELECT XXX)
GROUP BY comment.sender
```

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to also check the comment.sender, but it is lost on me for now

Comment: Ah I see - And I also noticed an error in my SQL. I'll update to include both. Please check it again in a minute...

Comment: I think this is closer, but I'm looking for users that are either the comment.sender OR comment_recipient.user_id, which is why I was thinking that I needed to join comment twice in my first attempt. A user will never be both

Comment: I think you could add that by simply changing the last AND statement... I'm just not 100% clear on what you asked for. So you want both a list of everyone who reports to a user (e.g. the manager/etc) who received the comment, as well as the poster of the comment itself? Wouldn't this just be a fixed number from the comments table (e.g. SELECT from comments where sender=X)?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'm trying to figure out how many users are participating. I want to count a user if they have given or received a comment in the last 7 days. I want to group this query by user.id because I don't want to count a user twice if they have given and recieved or if they are included in multiple comments

Comment: If its just based on participation, could you just select from the comments & receipts table? If all we need was comments posted & comments received (a count of), just count both and add them. I'll update with another method of doing this shortly.